# filter the gremlin results

Tags: filter, gremlin

I am new to Gremlin and I am using Gremlin 3.0.2 with Stardog 5.0. I wrote this query to find out paths between two entities in schema.org ontology. Below is the output -

```
gremlin>`g.V().hasLabel('Canal').repeat(both().simplePath()).until(g.V().hasLabel('Continent')).path().limit(5)`
```

> ==>[v[Canal], v[rdf-schema#Class]]
>   ==>[v[Canal], v[BodyOfWater], v[Landform], v[Continent]]
>   ==>[v[Canal], v[BodyOfWater], v[rdf-schema#Class], v[Continent]]
>   ==>[v[Canal], v[BodyOfWater], v[Pond], v[rdf-schema#Class], v[Continent]]
>   ==>[v[Canal], v[BodyOfWater], v[OceanBodyOfWater], v[rdf-schema#Class], v[Continent]]

I am unable to figure out a way to eliminate all the paths that has "rdf-schema#Class" in them. Please could someone suggest a solution? I want to do the filtering using Gremlin. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it would be to apply a post filter to the path that is returned. So for example, if you had something like this:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().outE('created').inV().path()
==>[v[1],e[9][1-created->3],v[3]]
==>[v[4],e[10][4-created->5],v[5]]
==>[v[4],e[11][4-created->3],v[3]]
==>[v[6],e[12][6-created->3],v[3]]
```

and wanted to get rid of the edge, you could do something like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().outE('created').inV().path().
......1>   local(unfold().filter(__.not(hasLabel('created'))).fold())
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[4],v[3]]
==>[v[6],v[3]]
```

So that new line basically just says, for each path item, unfold it, do some filter on the label for those that aren't "created", and then fold the path back up to a list.

Comment: Stephen, any way to get back to property values after doing the filter step? A lot of times I'll use something like path().by(Valuemap.... Is there a way to do something like path().filter(...).by(valueMap(...

Comment: you can't do `path().filter().by()`. what are you filtering though? the `Path` object itself? removing paths from the stream? perhaps this you should create a new question for this rather than have us tuck answer here in the comments?

Comment: thanks Stephen, posted a question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379910/gremlin-post-filter-path