# Gremlin Post Filter Path

Tags: filter, gremlin

I have a gremlin query that follows this pattern:

```
g.V().has('LOCATION', textContains('FLORIDA')).
repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath()).emit().times(5).
has('LOCATION',textContains('VIRGINIA')).
path().by(valueMap('LOCATION')).dedup()
```

Output could look something like this:

```
FLORIDA-->ALABAMA-->TENNESSEE-->VIRGINIA

FLORIDA-->GEORGIA-->TENNESSEE-->VIRGINIA

FLORIDA-->GEORGIA-->SOUTH CAROLINA-->NORTH CAROLINA-->VIRGINIA

etc...
```

Is there a way to filter after the path step to get only routes that go through ALABAMA (for instance). ALABAMA might not always be the second hop either so it would need to be dynamic enough to look across the whole path regardless of where the state to include might fall. Another wrinkle is there could be multiple states to filter on, for instance something like show me paths that include ALABAMA or include SOUTH CAROLINA or etc. In the actual application of this query there are multiple properties fed into the valueMap() as well but just tried to simplify it here. This could be similar to this question:

[filter the gremlin results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132477/filter-the-gremlin-results)

but I can't figure out how to get back to a valueMap() after the filter step without an error. I tried something like this but wasn't sure where to go from here:

```
g.V().has('LOCATION', textContains('FLORIDA')).
repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath()).emit().times(5).
has('LOCATION',textContains('VIRGINIA')).
path().filter(unfold().has('LOCATION', textContains('ALABAMA'))).
by(valueMap('LOCATION')).dedup()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `sack` to track this. Here is an example from Practical Gremlin that should help. The query finds routes that go from Austin to Edinburgh with at least one stop in Manchester. Similar to your Alabama use case. If Manchester is encountered along the path, a sack is incremented by one. As `simplePath` is used a location will never be visited twice. If, by the time EDI is reached, the sack contains a 1 then we know we went via MAN.

```
g.withSack(0).V().
  has('code','AUS').
  repeat(out().simplePath().has('country',within('US','UK')).
         choose(has('code','MAN'),sack(sum).by(constant(1)))).
    until(has('code','EDI')).
  where(sack().is(1)).
  path().by('code').
  limit(10)
```

For further reading http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#via

Comment: Thanks Kelvin! Wouldn't have thought to use sack for this.