# Gremlin Sack Sum Once Per Distinct Value

Tags: filter, gremlin

Referencing this example from Practical Gremlin and this stack overflow post:

[Gremlin Post Filter Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379910/gremlin-post-filter-path)

```
  g.withSack(0).V().
  has('code','AUS').
  repeat(out().simplePath().has('country',within('US','UK')).
         choose(has('code','MAN'),sack(sum).by(constant(1)))).
    until(has('code','EDI')).
  where(sack().is(1)).
  path().by('code').
  limit(10)
```

Is it possible to perform a sack sum in such a way as to only sum the first time a property is found. For instance, instead of the 'code' property inside of the choose() which will only sum once per 'code' encountered thanks to the simplePath(), what if there was another property called 'airport_color'. As we perform the traversal, I would only want the sack sum to increment the first time it encountered 'blue' or 'white' as an example, even though multiple airports could have the same color as we go through the traversal. This would help me in the where() clause because, if I had a couple of colors I was interested in looking for as an example (maybe blue and white), I could set the where() clause to be equal to two and know that two wasn't arrived at just because I passed through blue twice but because blue and white was encountred.

I tried using aggregation to make the sack sum increment only on the first encounter but couldn't get it to work, something like this:

```
g.withSack(0).V().
has('code','AUS').
repeat(out().simplePath().has('country',within('US','UK')).
     choose(has('airport_color','blue').has('airport_color', without('airport_color_agg')),sack(sum).by(constant(1))).
     aggregate('airport_color_agg').by('airport_color')).
until(has('code','EDI')).
where(sack().is(1)).
path().by('code').
limit(10)
```

There could be multiple colors in the choose() via or() but I limited it to just one to keep the example more straightforward.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you looking to just add 1 to the count for each unique occurrence of a property value? If so I would collect them all in the sack, then later on  `dedup` them before counting. The tricky part is that `store` and `aggregate` are global, whereas `sack` is per traverser. If this sounds like what you need, I can add an answer with an example.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, I think what you are describing is what I'm looking for. Ahead of time, I would know the property values that I'm interested in. On those property values I would want to add 1 to the count for each unique occurrence. An example would be great, thanks for your help. – 
r

Comment: OK I will add an answer that shows one way of doing this.

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to do this using a `path` step and then a little post processing. If this approach does not work for your case, let me know and we can explore some variations on this query.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, interesting use of sideEffect(). Is there a way to filter when doing post processing just to say keep only the paths that encountered everything in the 'want' list shown in the below answer? I would still want to see the whole path the traversal took but would only be interested in paths that went through the 'want' list.

Comment: I'll add a comment under the answer just to make it clear what it applies to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sample graph below:

```java
g.addV('A').property(id,'a1').property('color','red').as('a1').
  addV('A').property(id,'a2').property('color','blue').as('a2').
  addV('A').property(id,'a3').property('color','red').as('a3').
  addV('A').property(id,'a4').property('color','yellow').as('a4').
  addV('A').property(id,'a5').property('color','green').as('a5').
  addV('A').property(id,'a6').property('color','blue').as('a6').
  addE('R').from('a1').to('a2').
  addE('R').from('a2').to('a3').
  addE('R').from('a3').to('a4').
  addE('R').from('a4').to('a5').
  addE('R').from('a5').to('a6')
```

we can inspect the path through the graph as follows:

```java
g.V('a1').
  repeat(out()).
  until(not(out())).
  path().
    by('color')
```

which shows us the colors found

```
path[red, blue, red, yellow, green, blue]
```

the next thing we need to do is to remove the duplicates and filter out the colors not in our `want` list.

```java
g.withSideEffect('want',['red','green']).
  V('a1').
  repeat(out()).
  until(not(out())).
  path().
    by('color').
  dedup(local).
  unfold().
  where(within('want'))
```

which gives us:

```
red
green
```

finally, we just need to count them:

```java
g.withSideEffect('want',['red','green']).
  V('a1').
  repeat(out()).
  until(not(out())).
  path().
    by('color').
  dedup(local).
  unfold().
  where(within('want')).
  count()
```

Which, as expected, gives us:

```
2
```

**UPDATED 2022-09-01** To reflect discussion in comments.

To change the query so that only paths that visit each of the required colors at least once are returned, the previous steps leading up to the `count` need to be turned into a `filter`.

```java
g.withSideEffect('want',['red','green']).
  V('a1').
  repeat(out()).
  until(not(out())).
  filter(
    path().
      by('color').
    dedup(local).
    unfold().
    where(within('want')).
    count().is(2)).
  path()
```

which for our sample graph returns:

```
1   path[v[a1], v[a2], v[a3], v[a4], v[a5], v[a6]]
```

The query as written gets the job done and hopefully is not too hard to follow. There are some things we could change/improve.

1. Pass in the count for the `is` step as another parameter like the `want` list.
2. Rather than pass in a parameter, use the size of the want list instead. This makes the query a little more complex.
3. Use a `sack` as the query proceeds to collect the colors seen. The query gets more complex in that case as, while you can maintain a list in a `sack`, updating it requires a few extra steps.

Here is the query rewritten to use a `sack`. This assumes the start node has a color that should be included. If that is not the case, the first `sack(assign)` can be removed and a `withSack([])` added after the `withSideEffect`.

```java
g.withSideEffect('want',['red','green']).
  V('a1').
  sack(assign).by(values('color').fold()).
  repeat(out().sack(assign).by(union(sack().unfold(),values('color')).fold())).
  until(not(out())).
  filter(
    sack().
    unfold().
    dedup().
    where(within('want')).
    count().is(2)).
  path()
```

Comment: Responding to the comments above. Is the ask to return the path IF (and only IF), colors on the "want" list are encountered only once? If yes, that will make the query a little more complex for sure.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, we would be looking to return a path if and only if all colors are encountered on the "want" list at least once.

Comment: Thanks that helps clarify the goal. I have edited the answer to show one way of doing this and added some observations about alternative approaches that could be taken.

Comment: That is very powerful and both approaches worked for my use case. Sorry for the back and forth it took to get there but your help is very much appreciated.