# How can I avoid collecting multiple instances of vertices and edges?

Tags: gremlin, graph-traversal, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I've created a query to return all "descendant" edges and vertices for a particular queried vertex.

The **query works**, but it **duplicates edges and vertices with each iteration** of the repeat step. At the end of the repeat step, the traverser takes the tail of these aggregated collections, tossing away all the previous iterations of aggregated data.

How can I avoid all these **pointless collections** and just create the **tail collection** that is returned at the end?

It is as if each iteration of **repeat** caches the complete result as a new collection. For example, if we track _item across **iterations** we get:

1. **3**__A.1.2
2. **3**__A.1.2 , **4**__A.1.2.1
3. **3**__A.1.2 , **4**__A.1.2.1 , **5**__A.1.2.1.**1**
4. **3**__A.1.2 , **4**__A.1.2.1 , **5**__A.1.2.1.**1** , **5**__A.1.2.1.**2**

At the end of the query, **the tail step** returns **iteration number 4**.

**Graph:**

[image]

**Query:**

```
g.V("3__A.1.2") 
.inE("hasFacilityItem") //steps to edge toward Item
.repeat(
    hasLabel("hasFacilityItem")
    .sideEffect(
        fold().aggregate("_hasFacilityItem")
    )
    .sideEffect(
        outV().fold().aggregate("_item")
    )
    .inV().hasLabel("FacilityItem")
    .sideEffect(
        fold().aggregate("_facilityItem")
    )
    .sideEffect(
        coalesce(outE("containedByFacilityItem").not(outV().has("id", "3__A.1.2")), constant()) //returns [] if edge is first queried
            .fold().aggregate("_contained")
    )
    .sideEffect(
        coalesce(outE("containsFacilityItem"), constant()) //returns [] if edge is not extant
            .fold().aggregate("_contains")
    )
    .coalesce(outE("containsFacilityItem").inV().inE("hasFacilityItem"), constant()) //returns [] if last vertex was reached
)
.emit()
.select("_item").tail().as("item")
.select("_hasFacilityItem").tail().as("hasFacilityItem")
.select("_facilityItem").tail().as("facilityItem")
.select("_contained").tail().as("contained")
.select("_contains").tail().as("contains")
.select("item", "hasFacilityItem", "facilityItem", "contained", "contains")
```

**Setup:** Note: I wrote this by hand..

```
g
.addV('Item').as('_3__A.1.2')
.addV('Item').as('_4__A.1.2.1')
.addV('Item').as('_5__A.1.2.1.1')
.addV('Item').as('_5__A.1.2.1.2')

.addV('FacilityItem').as('3__A.1.2')
.addV('FacilityItem').as('4__A.1.2.1')
.addV('FacilityItem').as('5__A.1.2.1.1')
.addV('FacilityItem').as('5__A.1.2.1.2')

.addE('hasFacilityItem').from('_3__A.1.2').to('3__A.1.2')
.addE('hasFacilityItem').from('_4__A.1.2.1').to('4__A.1.2.1')
.addE('hasFacilityItem').from('_5__A.1.2.1.1').to('5__A.1.2.1.1')
.addE('hasFacilityItem').from('_5__A.1.2.1.2').to('5__A.1.2.1.2')

.addE('hasItem').from('3__A.1.2').to('_3__A.1.2')
.addE('hasItem').from('4__A.1.2.1').to('_4__A.1.2.1')
.addE('hasItem').from('5__A.1.2.1.1').to('_5__A.1.2.1.1')
.addE('hasItem').from('5__A.1.2.1.2').to('_5__A.1.2.1.2')

.addE('containsFacilityItem').from('3__A.1.2').to('4__A.1.2.1')
.addE('containsFacilityItem').from('4__A.1.2.1').to('5__A.1.2.1.1')
.addE('containsFacilityItem').from('4__A.1.2.1').to('5__A.1.2.1.2')

.addE('containedByFacilityItem').from('5__A.1.2.1.2').to('4__A.1.2.1')
.addE('containedByFacilityItem').from('5__A.1.2.1.1').to('4__A.1.2.1')
.addE('containedByFacilityItem').from('4__A.1.2.1').to('3__A.1.2')
```

Comment: It would help provide tested answers if you could provide the `addV` and `addE` steps that create the sample graph, and also an example of the results you wish to produce. An example of creating a sample graph can be found in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546575/gremlin-sack-sum-once-per-distinct-value

Comment: Something that I'm doing with aggregate and repeat is causing the duplication. I've tried adding "local" to the aggregate function thinking that would limit the data collected, but cosmos doesn't understand the scope and chokes on it.

Comment: Keep in mind that as Gremlin traverses a graph the paths taken may visit the same vertex and edges as they go. As a simple example, consider the paths `A-->B-->C` and `A-->B-->D` , they both visit A and B.  Can you perhaps just `dedup` your aggregates? Overall though I think the query can be simplified a lot. One way might be just to capture the `path` and post filter it.

Comment: Not a bad idea. A path query was what I WAS previously doing.

However, a path query doesn't contain all the data that I am collecting here. A path grabs each traversal from source to destination. I have subtraversals for each vertex in the main traversal that steps a completely different direction to grab 2 edges and another vertex that a path or tree query would miss.

Comment: Fair enough, `path` will not see the activity that goes on inside a `sideEffect`. The "quick fix might just be to `dedup` all the aggregated values. If you have time to add the `addV` and `addE` steps to the question it will be a lot easier to provide tested alternatives.

Comment: I added setup. Rather than using partitions for this question, I changed the Item label nodes by adding a leading underscore to the id. Additionally, I know that some versions do not understand an empty "constant()". If you encounter this, the coalesce step to constant() can be replaced with the first parameter of coalesce without breaking the query.