# Gremlin: Traversing back graph, aggregating the results

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDHkU.jpg

Hello! I have a graph like in the picture above.

I am trying to do a query that will traverse the graph until leaf vertices are reached,
make some computation for each leaf that will retrieve a list of vertices and then traverse back to the above level, aggregating the results from the children vertices in a unique list of vertices.

Now on each parent vertex, I will run the same computations and add the resulting list (in the picture represented as the list before +) with vertices to the aggregated list.
This is repeated for all the levels until first vertex is reached.

The question is, once I reached the leaves and got a list of vertices for each leaf, how do I traverse back to parents, aggregating the results in a single list.

I am using AWS Neptune with gremlin python.

This is the query I made so far that reaches the leaves and get a list for each leaf traversal:
`g.V(vertexId).repeat(out()).until(outE().count().is(0)).[additional steps that return a list of vertices]`

Sample graph:

```
g.addV("Website").property("name", "www.ex1.com").property("type", "root")
.addV("Website").property("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1")
.addV("Website").property("name", "www.ex1.com/sub2")
.addV("Website").property("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1/about")
.addV("Endpoint").property("name", "Node 1")
.addV("Endpoint").property("name", "Node 2")
.addV("Endpoint").property("name", "Node 3")
.addV("Endpoint").property("name", "Node 4")
.addE("SUBPATH").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com")).to(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1"))
.addE("SUBPATH").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com")).to(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub2"))
.addE("SUBPATH").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1")).to(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1/about"))
.addE("RELATED").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com")).to(V().has("name", "Node 3"))
.addE("RELATED").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1")).to(V().has("name", "Node 1"))
.addE("RELATED").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1")).to(V().has("name", "Node 4"))
.addE("RELATED").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub2")).to(V().has("name", "Node 2"))
.addE("RELATED").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1/about")).to(V().has("name", "Node 2"))
.addE("RELATED").from(V().has("name", "www.ex1.com/sub1/about")).to(V().has("name", "Node 4"))
```

**Edit:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDHkU.jpg

Hello everyone, thanks for the help and sorry for the wait. I constructed a more detailed graph to better illustrate what the problem is. I have a bunch of these "Website" nodes in a hierarchical tree-like fashion, and each of them is hooked up to an arbitrary number of distinct nodes with the same Label. We can call those nodes endpoints.

I have to find out for each Website node in the tree how many distinct endpoints there are for both that node and everything beneath it (union of all endpoints).

I have done this in the brute-force way of recalculating the set of endpoints for each node's sub-tree using a repeat(out().as("")) and afterwards selecting every child node in order to traverse towards the endpoints all at once in order to dedup() them.

```java
g.V()
  .hasLabel("Website").as("k")
  .project("website", "count")
    .by(select("k").by(T.id))
    .by(
      repeat(out().as("k")).until(outE().count().is(0))
      .select(all, "k")
      .unfold()
      .out("Related")
      .dedup()
      .count())
```

I am now searching for a memoization type approach where I could gather the endpoints for each leaf and use the calculated set when going another level up without having to recalculate them.

The sack() would have been a great candidate for this task, however I couldn't make it work in Gremlin-Java with Sets or custom merge operators. Perhaps I was just doing something wrong. If it were possible it would then be very easy to traverse into the leaves of the tree, get the endpoints, store the vertices into the sack set, go back towards the root, append the parent's endpoints to the set and perhaps merge the parent's traversals sacks if it has more than one child.

Comment: While diagrams are nice, if you can add the `addV` and `addE` steps that create a sample graph to the question, that will help people provide tested answers. An example of creating such a graph is shown in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546575/gremlin-sack-sum-once-per-distinct-value Also, it would be helpful if you could show an example of the output you would like to have the query produce.

Comment: Thank you @KelvinLawrence . I added a sample graph and the desired output is the list shown in diagram near the root node.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear what you are looking for as the diagram does not label the nodes with their IDs. Do you want for any given start node the hierarchy beneath it (its subtree) or are you looking for something broader?

Comment: I updated the question with a more detailed explanation of the issue as well as a new graph sample data and diagram. Thank you