# Gremlin - how to show IN edges and vertex for specific vertex

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-notebook

I need to show a specific vertex with IN edges and related vertex.
I tried with this but I don't have a graph

`%%gremlin -p v-d,oute,inv, -d name g.V().has('name','my_value').outE().inV().path().by(elementMap())`

how can I modify my command?

For example, I have created this graph
[vertex OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5VW7.png)

Now I want to show INCOMING edges and vertexs for a specific vertex

Comment: You are mixing two sets of query hints there. the `-p` hint is only needed when you don't have a `path().by(elementMap())`. The `-d` hint is used to label nodes in the visualization. If you can add a small test graph to the question and an explanation of what you want the output to look like it will be easier to provide a tested answer. You will find an example showing an easy way to create a sample graph here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546575/gremlin-sack-sum-once-per-distinct-value

Comment: Hi have added my idea about the graph that I want

Comment: The visualization will be for the `path` created in the query. You cannot expand an existing visualization. So to see the incoming edges you will need to either add that to the current query or create a new one that contains `inE` and `outV` steps.

Comment: I want another query for my result

Comment: I resolved my problem: g.V().has('name','my_name').inE().outV().path().by(elementMap())

Comment: I'm glad that was it. I copied my text above to the answer in case others have the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visualization will be for the `path` created in the query. You cannot expand an existing visualization currently. So to see the incoming edges you will need to either add that to the current query or create a new one that contains `inE` and `outV` steps