# Can Gremlin aggregate the values of edges connected to the same node?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Suppose you have one node with label, 'A'. This node is connected to many nodes with label, 'B', via edges with label 'e'. For a given B, there can be many edges between A and B with the same label, 'e'. On each edge, there is a property, 'p'.

We want to aggregate all the 'p' properties from edges connected from A, to the same B.

E.g. suppose we have a particular B. One edge between A and that B has a 'p' value of 'foo', and another edge connecting to the same B has a 'p' value of 'bar'. Their aggregation would be:

`{'e': {'p': ['foo', 'bar']}`

How can this be achieved?

At the moment, I have this query:

```
g.V()
    .hasLabel('A').as('A')
    .outE().hasLabel('e').as('e')
    .inV().hasLabel('B').as('B')
    .select('A', 'e', 'B')
    .by(valueMap())
```

It would produce an output like this:

```
[
    {{'A': {'name': ['john']}, {'e': {'p': ['foo']}, 'B': {'place': 'Qatar'}},
    {{'A': {'name': ['john']}, {'e': {'p': ['bar']}, 'B': {'place': 'Qatar'}},
    {{'A': {'name': ['john']}, {'e': {'p': ['hello']}, 'B': {'place': 'Argentina'}},
    {{'A': {'name': ['john']}, {'e': {'p': ['goodbye']}, 'B': {'place': 'Argentina'}}
]
```

Whereas, I would want this:

```
[
    {{'A': {'name': ['john']}, {'e': {'p': ['foo', 'bar']}, 'B': {'place': 'Qatar'}},
    {{'A': {'name': ['john']}, {'e': {'p': ['hello', 'goodbye']}, 'B': {'place': 'Argentina'}}
]
```

Comment: You likely want to look at using a step like `group` that will reduce the traversers into collections. For example you might do something like `group().by('place')`. If you have the steps handy to create the test graph, and can add those to the question, it will make providing a tested answer easier. An example of building a test graph can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546575/gremlin-sack-sum-once-per-distinct-value):

Comment: I added an answer based on the output shown in the question. From the query in the answer you should be able to get close to the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data from the question, the following graph can be built:

```java
g.addV('A').property('name','john').property(id,'J1').as('j').
  addV('B').property('place','Qatar').property(id,'Q1').as('q').
  addV('B').property('place','Argentina').property(id,'A1').as('a').
  addE('e').from('j').to('q').property('p','foo').
  addE('e').from('j').to('q').property('p','bar').
  addE('e').from('j').to('a').property('p','hello').
  addE('e').from('j').to('a').property('p','goodbye')
```

Using that graph, we can get close to what you are looking for using a nested `group` step. From these building blocks you should be able to construct other variations:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('A').as('a').outE('e').as('e').inV().hasLabel('B').as('b').
  group().
    by(select('a').values('name')).
    by(group().
      by(select('b').values('place')).
      by(select('e').values('p').fold()))
```

Which yields

```java
    {'john': {'Argentina': ['hello', 'goodbye'], 'Qatar': ['foo', 'bar']}}
```

Using `valueMap` we can add the keys to the result:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('A').as('a').outE('e').as('e').inV().hasLabel('B').as('b').
  group().
    by(select('a').values('name')).
    by(group().
      by(select('b').valueMap('place')).
      by(select('e').valueMap('p').unfold().group().by(keys).by(values)))
```

Which produces

```java
{'john': {{'place': ('Argentina',)}: {'p': ['hello', 'goodbye']}, {'place': ('Qatar',)}: {'p': ['foo', 'bar']}}}
```

So, what we end up with, for each person (just "john" in this case), is a list containing each place they visited along with the "p" values for each edge that got them there). You can then select into that nested structure any way you need to to extract individual pieces. With these building blocks you should be able to tweak things to get any variations of this output that you prefer.