# How can I do conditional sort on Gremlin/Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I am trying to build a query that will return a Vertex both edges, and sort them conditionally by value of a different property according to whether the original Vertex is the out Vertex or in Vertex in the given edge, I have two properties that will comply with this sort ("origin_pinned" & "target_pinned"), if an edge in Vertex is the original vertex I want to use "origin_pinned" value if its the out vertex then I want to use "target_pinned" value

This must be one query

I tried to run the following query but does not seem to have effect:

```
g.V('id123').bothE().order().by(values(choose(inV().is(V('id123')), 
constant('origin_pinned'), constant('target_pinned'))), desc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values` step will not work the way you are trying to use it. You did not include any sample data in the question, but using the air-routes data set, the query can most likely be simplified as shown below:

```java
gremlin> g.V(44).as('a').
......1>   bothE().
......2>   order().
......3>     by(coalesce(
......4>         where(inV().as('a')).constant('origin_pinned'),
......5>         constant('target_pinned')))

==>e[57948][3742-contains->44]
==>e[54446][3728-contains->44]
==>e[4198][13-route->44]
==>e[4776][31-route->44]
==>e[4427][20-route->44]
==>e[4015][8-route->44]
==>e[5061][44-route->8]
==>e[5062][44-route->13]
==>e[5063][44-route->20]
==>e[5064][44-route->31]
```

and to prove the reverse also works

```java
gremlin> g.V(44).as('a').
......1>   bothE().
......2>   order().
......3>     by(coalesce(
......4>         where(outV().as('a')).constant('origin_pinned'),
......5>         constant('target_pinned')))

==>e[5061][44-route->8]
==>e[5062][44-route->13]
==>e[5063][44-route->20]
==>e[5064][44-route->31]
==>e[57948][3742-contains->44]
==>e[54446][3728-contains->44]
==>e[4198][13-route->44]
==>e[4776][31-route->44]
==>e[4427][20-route->44]
==>e[4015][8-route->44]
```

To check things are working as expected, we can do:

```java
gremlin> g.V(44).as('a').
......1>   bothE().as('e').
......2>   coalesce(
......3>     where(inV().as('a')).constant('origin_pinned'),
......4>     constant('target_pinned')).as('p').
......5>     order().
......6>   select('e','p')

==>[e:e[57948][3742-contains->44],p:origin_pinned]
==>[e:e[54446][3728-contains->44],p:origin_pinned]
==>[e:e[4198][13-route->44],p:origin_pinned]
==>[e:e[4776][31-route->44],p:origin_pinned]
==>[e:e[4427][20-route->44],p:origin_pinned]
==>[e:e[4015][8-route->44],p:origin_pinned]
==>[e:e[5061][44-route->8],p:target_pinned]
==>[e:e[5062][44-route->13],p:target_pinned]
==>[e:e[5063][44-route->20],p:target_pinned]
==>[e:e[5064][44-route->31],p:target_pinned]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, really helpful though I am still not getting the exact behavior I wanted, the sort is working on the direction of the edge but not by the value

for example lets say origin_pinned has a numeric value and im trying to do descending order this is similar to what I am gettings:
```==>e[5061][44-route->8] 1
==>e[5062][44-route->13] 1
==>e[5063][44-route->20] 1
==>e[5064][44-route->31] 1
==>e[57948][3742-contains->44] 1
==>e[54446][3728-contains->44] 4
==>e[4198][13-route->44] 1
==>e[4776][31-route->44] 1
==>e[4427][20-route->44] 1```

Comment: what I mean is that the result is parted to origin_pinned and target_pinned but out of the results which have origin_pinned applied on, they are not sorted by that field within themselves

Comment: Are you able to add the steps to the question that build a sample graph? That will help provide a tested answer.  Please also add the precise output you are looking to generate.

Comment: here is an example
https://freeimage.host/i/HIqNu7p

Comment: in the 3 top edges the main Vertex is the in vertex, and in the rest its the out vertex, but in the top three its not sorting by that origin pinned property as you can see

Comment: If you can add a sample graph to the question it will really help give you a tested answer. I think I understand what you are looking to do but it would really help to see a sample graph. A few steps such as the ones [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853187/can-gremlin-aggregate-the-values-of-edges-connected-to-the-same-node) will really help.

Comment: here is an example graph: https://gremlify.com/ab3fp6b3zs
when running your first query on V1 vertex I get the order: e5,e4,e1,e2,e3 (your second query or just doing by step with desc order, returns the next order e1,e2,e3,e5,e4) I aim to get the next order of edges: e3,e5,e1,e2,e4

Answer (score 0):

managed to figure it out with the help of [Kelvin Lawrence's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442034/kelvin-lawrence) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74894060/12486048):

```
g.V('id123').as('a').bothE().order().by(
coalesce(
where(
outV().as('a')).values('origin_pinned'),
values('target_pinned'), 
constant(0)), 
desc)
```