# Create a group vertex for each group, and create outgoing edges to the group vertices

Tags: gremlin

I have a gremlin query which groups vertices based on two properties

```
g.V().hasLabel("PERSON").
  group().
    by(values('favorite_brand', 'favorite_color').fold()).
  next()
```

It returns a list of each group mapped to the list of the vertices in group

```
1   {('adidas', 'blue'): [v[123], v[456]]}
2   {('nike', 'red'): [v[789]]}
```

How can I: for each group, create a vertex with an outgoing edge to all the vertices in that group and also set the new group vertex properties to be the same

For example for the above, I would create two new vertices. Group Vertex 1 would have 'favorite_brand' as adidas and 'favorite_color' as blue and would have two outgoing edges to the two vertices 123 and 456.

Same for Group Vertex 2

Is there a way in gremlin to carry this query or do I have to store the returned hashmap in a variable and for loop in my lambda to create new vertices? I'm familiar with addV step but how would I iterate through each element in the hashmap and then access the list value? Thanks!

I have look at the tinkerpop official documentation to understand group step but then didn't find enough information on how to iterate through results and perform actions

Comment: This should definitely be doable in Gremlin. Do you by chance have a sample graph you can add to the question in the form of `addV` and `addE` steps? That makes providing a tested answer a lot easier. An example of creating a small sample graph can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853187/can-gremlin-aggregate-the-values-of-edges-connected-to-the-same-node)

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer using the air-routes data set, but you should be able to map what I did onto your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having your data, the answer below is built using the air-routes data set. The initial group can be built using:

```java
g.V().hasId('3','8','12','13','14').
  group().
    by(values('region', 'country').fold()).
  unfold()
```

which yields

```
1   {('US-CA', 'US'): [v[13]]}
2   {('US-NY', 'US'): [v[12], v[14]]}
3   {('US-TX', 'US'): [v[3], v[8]]}
```

From there we can build a query to unroll the group while creating the new nodes and edges.

```java
g.V().hasId('3','8','12','13','14').
  group().
    by(values('region', 'country').fold()).
  unfold().as('grp').
  addV('group').as('new-node').
    property('region',select(keys).limit(local,1)).
    property('country',select(keys).tail(local)).
  sideEffect(select('grp').select(values).unfold().addE('new-edge').from('new-node'))
```

which shows us the nodes created but will also have created the edges inside the `sideEffect`.

```
1   v[26c2d653-5e9c-3ec9-0854-6ed2a212c63b]
2   v[80c2d653-5e9c-b838-063c-82f6d21cd6e5]
3   v[42c2d653-5e9d-31c7-2c02-c7bf72fe8e38]
```

We can use the query below to verify everything has worked.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('group').out().path().by(valueMap()).by(id())
```

Which returns

```
1   path[{'region': ['US-CA'], 'country': ['US']}, 13]
2   path[{'region': ['US-NY'], 'country': ['US']}, 12]
3   path[{'region': ['US-NY'], 'country': ['US']}, 14]
4   path[{'region': ['US-TX'], 'country': ['US']}, 3]
5   path[{'region': ['US-TX'], 'country': ['US']}, 8]
```

I used Amazon Neptune to build this answer but it should work on other TinkerPop compliant stores.