# Finding suspicious logins using amazon neptune graph database

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a below structure of graph loaded in amazon neptune.
[image: Below is graph description]

**In words graph can be described as:** Device is getting accessed from location and Device is logging into the account.

**Problem Statement:** I want to find suspecious logins to the account.

**How?:** Ideally one account should get accessed from only one device. If it is getting accessed from more than 1 device then one of the login is suspicious. But this becomes false when customer gets a new device. To increase accuracy we can say that if device which is accessed later is atleast 1km away from device which was accessed earlier. Then it becomes suspicious.

I am trying to write the query for the same in gremlin query language but haven't gone very far and **looking for a query:** to find account and devices where account was accessed from more than one device and both the devices are atleast 100km away from each other.

**EDIT:**

Sample graph created using below commands:

```
g.addV("TEST_LOCATION").property(id, "location1").property("latitude", 10.855641295031102).property("longitude", 76.62664361108531).next()
g.addV("TEST_DEVICE").property(id, "device1").next()
g.addE("TEST_ACCESSED").from(__.V('location1')).to(__.V('device1')).property(id, "accessed1").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T09:41:02')).next()
g.addV("TEST_ACCOUNT").property(id, "2023658452").property("accountNumber", "2023658452").next()
g.addE("TEST_LOGGED_IN").from(__.V('device1')).to(__.V('2023658452')).property(id, "login1").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T09:41:02')).next()

g.addV("TEST_LOCATION").property(id, "location2").property("latitude", 10.856369018807927).property("longitude", 76.62525939933491).next()
g.addV("TEST_DEVICE").property(id, "device2").next()
g.addE("TEST_ACCESSED").from(__.V('location2')).to(__.V('device2')).property(id, "accessed2").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T10:41:02')).next()
g.addE("TEST_LOGGED_IN").from(__.V('device2')).to(__.V('2023658452')).property(id, "login2").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T10:41:02')).next()


g.addV("TEST_LOCATION").property(id, "location3").property("latitude", 12.9578933).property("longitude", 77.7446321).next()
g.addV("TEST_DEVICE").property(id, "device3").next()
g.addE("TEST_ACCESSED").from(__.V('location3')).to(__.V('device3')).property(id, "accessed3").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T11:41:02')).next()
g.addV("TEST_ACCOUNT").property(id, "2025487996").property("accountNumber", "2025487996").next()
g.addE("TEST_LOGGED_IN").from(__.V('device3')).to(__.V('2025487996')).property(id, "login3").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T11:41:02')).next()


g.addV("TEST_LOCATION").property(id, "location4").property("latitude", 37.4219983).property("longitude", -122.084).next()
g.addV("TEST_DEVICE").property(id, "device4").next()
g.addE("TEST_ACCESSED").from(__.V('location4')).to(__.V('device4')).property(id, "accessed4").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T12:41:02')).next()
g.addE("TEST_LOGGED_IN").from(__.V('device4')).to(__.V('2025487996')).property(id, "login4").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T12:41:02')).next()


g.addV("TEST_LOCATION").property(id, "location5").property("latitude", 10.85569589).property("longitude", 76.626646584).next()
g.addV("TEST_DEVICE").property(id, "device5").next()
g.addE("TEST_ACCESSED").from(__.V('location5')).to(__.V('device5')).property(id, "accessed5").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T09:41:02')).next()
g.addV("TEST_LOCATION").property(id, "location6").property("latitude", 10.85569965).property("longitude", 76.626646745).next()
g.addE("TEST_ACCESSED").from(__.V('location6')).to(__.V('device5')).property(id, "accessed6").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T09:41:02')).next()
g.addV("TEST_ACCOUNT").property(id, "2004589564").property("accountNumber", "2004589564").next()
g.addE("TEST_LOGGED_IN").from(__.V('device5')).to(__.V('2004589564')).property(id, "login5").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T09:41:02')).next()
g.addE("TEST_LOGGED_IN").from(__.V('device5')).to(__.V('2004589564')).property(id, "login6").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T10:41:02')).next()

g.addV("TEST_LOCATION").property(id, "location7").property("latitude", 10.85569951).property("longitude", 76.626646951).next()
g.addV("TEST_DEVICE").property(id, "device6").next()
g.addE("TEST_ACCESSED").from(__.V('location7')).to(__.V('device6')).property(id, "accessed7").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T10:41:02')).next()
g.addE("TEST_LOGGED_IN").from(__.V('device6')).to(__.V('2004589564')).property(id, "login7").property("loggedInAt", datetime('2022-11-29T10:41:02')).next()
```

Expected Output:

```
Account No: 2025487996
Accessed from device: device3 From location: location3
Accessed from device: device4 From location: location4
Distance between these devices is: 14040 km
```

**Explanation of output:** Account was accessed by multiple devices from different locations. We wanted only those devices and accounts which were accessed from locations with distance 100 km away from each other.

Comment: This might be a good place to start when looking at calculating distances between two coordinates: https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#GreatCircle

Comment: Happy to help with the creation of a Gremlin query to do this. What would help a lot is if you could add to the question the `addV` and `addE` steps that build a small sample graph, and also describe a little more the output you are looking to achieve. As mentioned in the comment above, calculating Haversine Great Circle distances using Gremlin is quite possible.

Comment: Examples of creating a sample graph can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853187/can-gremlin-aggregate-the-values-of-edges-connected-to-the-same-node)

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I have added sample input and sample output. addV and addE steps as well.

Comment: I have added an answer - I can add to it based on any additional discussion in comments etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the sample graph. That makes writing an answer much easier.

To begin with, finding the devices and locations that accessed the account is as simple as:

```java
gremlin> g.V('2025487996').in('TEST_LOGGED_IN').in('TEST_ACCESSED').path().by(id)

==>[2025487996,device4,location4]
==>[2025487996,device3,location3]
```

With that foundation we can then extract the coordinates and format the results a bit more nicely.

```java
gremlin> g.V('2025487996').as('ac').
......1>   in('TEST_LOGGED_IN').as('dev').
......2>   in('TEST_ACCESSED').as('loc').
......3>   project('account','device','location').
......4>     by(select('ac').id()).
......5>     by(select('dev').id()).
......6>     by(values('latitude','longitude').fold()) 

==>[account:2025487996,device:device4,location:[37.4219983,-122.084]]
==>[account:2025487996,device:device3,location:[12.9578933,77.7446321]]
```

As there are currently no GeoSpatial functions native to Gremlin, you have a few choices here.

1. Do the distance filtering in the application.
2. Use the [Haversine Great Circle Distance](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#GreatCircle) Gremlin query example and inject the points into that and filter based on the results.
3. Do the Haversine calculations in the application.
4. Store the points using something like a Geohash and do the calculations in the application using a GeoHash (or equivalent) library.

On the roadmap for Apache TinkerPop (date TBD) there is an item to add better GeoSpatial support to Gremlin. Until then, the best alternatives are going to be to do the calculation using the Harversine query, or do them in the application and just use the graph to find the relationships.

If you decide to try doing it all in Gremlin, changing the initial part of the query a little will make it fit more easily with the Haversine distance example.

```java
gremlin> g.V('2025487996').as('ac').
......1>   in('TEST_LOGGED_IN').as('dev').
......2>   in('TEST_ACCESSED').as('loc').
......3>   group().
......4>     by(select('dev').id()).
......5>     by(project('lat','lon').
......6>         by('latitude').
......7>         by('longitude')) 

==>[device3:[lat:12.9578933,lon:77.7446321],device4:[lat:37.4219983,lon:-122.084]]
```

Lastly

```java
gremlin> g.V('2025487996').as('ac').
......1>   in('TEST_LOGGED_IN').as('dev').
......2>   in('TEST_ACCESSED').as('loc').
......3>   group().
......4>     by(select('dev').id()).
......5>     by(project('lat','lon').
......6>         by('latitude').
......7>         by('longitude')).
......8>   project('src','dst').
......9>     by(limit(local,1).select(values).unfold()).
.....10>     by(tail(local,1).select(values).unfold()) 

==>[src:[lat:12.9578933,lon:77.7446321],dst:[lat:37.4219983,lon:-122.084]]
```

which creates a src/dst pair that can be plugged into the Harversine query.

So......we can now cut and paste in the relevant parts of the Harversine query.

```java
gremlin> g.withSideEffect("rdeg", 0.017453293).
......1>   withSideEffect("gcmiles",3956). 
......2>   V('2025487996').as('ac').
......3>   in('TEST_LOGGED_IN').as('dev').
......4>   in('TEST_ACCESSED').as('loc').
......5>   group().
......6>     by(select('dev').id()).
......7>     by(project('lat','lon').
......8>         by('latitude').
......9>         by('longitude')).
.....10>   project('src','dst').
.....11>     by(limit(local,1).select(values).unfold()).
.....12>     by(tail(local,1).select(values).unfold()).
.....13>   as('grp').
.....14>   project('ladiff','lgdiff','lat1','lon1','lat2','lon2').
.....15>     by(project('la1','la2').
.....16>          by(select('grp').select('src').select('lat')).
.....17>          by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lat')).
.....18>        math('(la2 - la1) * rdeg')).
.....19>     by(project('lg1','lg2').
.....20>          by(select('grp').select('src').select('lon')).
.....21>          by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lon')).
.....22>        math('(lg2 - lg1) * rdeg')).
.....23>     by(select('grp').select('src').select('lat')).
.....24>     by(select('grp').select('src').select('lon')).
.....25>     by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lat')).
.....26>     by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lon')).
.....27>   math('(sin(ladiff/2))^2 + cos(lat1*rdeg) * cos(lat2*rdeg) * (sin(lgdiff/2))^2').
.....28>   math('gcmiles * (2 * asin(sqrt(_)))')  

==>8719.402153569563
```

8,719 miles is approximately 14,032 kilometers.