# Gremlin traversing multiple paths with different sort and filter criteria

Tags: .net, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have two group of vertices in AWS Neptune db and following is the data representation of these vertices.
[image]

I want to traverse the edge that has creationDate (cd) less than or equal to some time, t.
There could be multiple edges fulfilling this criteria so, I want to traverse the edge which has the largest creation date or the edge which is most recent to the time t.

I also want to get the properties of that edge and the vertex to which it is connected to.

time t can differ for each input vertex so query should be robust to handle this scenario.

**Input**:

Id:P1 and cd: t2.2

Id:P2 and cd: t7.5

**Output**:

[{edge => cd:t2, vertex => Id:C1}, {edge => cd:t7, vertex: Id:C3}]

I am not sure how gremlin can traverse two paths with different starting vertices.
If I start with g.V('P1','P2') then how would I mention different 'cd' conditions for P1 and P2?

Comment: How are the dates on the edges stored? Epoch integers, actual datetime types, or something else? Knowing this will help with possible suggestions. If you could add a few `addV` and `addE` steps that build the sample graphs to the question that would help even more. This should be doable by filtering the edges, sorting them and picking the top one, but having a bit more information will help provide a tested answer.

Comment: A simple example of creating a graph for testing can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853187/can-gremlin-aggregate-the-values-of-edges-connected-to-the-same-node)